# ForEach Table, Union X,Y,Z

Tags: sql, foreach, union

I have a SQL DB with tables that are created and updated programmatically.

What is the best approach to creating a new table from all the tables in my DB?  The tables will be dynamic and are all the same columns.

I'm assuming Union with a Foreach, but want to make there isn't a better way.

I have only created the powershell to import the CSVs to my DB so far.

Comment: If the tables are all the same columns, are you sure you need separate tables in the first place?

Comment: Why not insert the data into the same table?

Comment: I knew it was too easy.  Thank you.